# How to plot two scatter plots on the same graphic using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a single file with three columns call them x,y,z; I need to plot on the same graphic x VS y and x VS z.

How to plot two scatter plot on the same graphic using gnuplot?

**EDIT** I know that to plot a single function I have to write something like

```
plot 'file name' using 1:2
```

I don't konw how to plot together 1:2 and 1:3

Comment: Sorry, but have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot `Y` and `Z` on the same axis with respect to `x`, then

```
plot "filename" u 1:2, "" u 1:3
```

If you want two different y-axes, that is, you want `y` on one axis and `z` on a secondary axis, then

```
set y2tics <start>,<incr>,<end>
plot "filename" u 1:2, "" u 1:3 axes x1y2
```

Note that `y2tics` lets you configure the secondary `y` axis; in particular, here it lets you decide the starting value, the ending vale, and the incrementation. Additionally, any command you know for `y` carries on for the secondary axis by using `y2` (for example, to set the label or range, use `y2label` or `y2range`).